# Control used to switch between pages of content

Tags: c#, winforms

In the form pictured below, the entire content of the left side changes when an item is selected on the right side. Which control can I use to accomplish this effect? I’ve tried a ListBox.

[image: Picture Of Form]

Comment: There are no standard controls with such behavior. Create your own.

Comment: Dear Alexander what you mean with standard controls

Comment: You need to update the content on left side on the selection change event of item on the right.

Comment: Dear Mukil you mean i use a listbox and then update but how can i update what event i use if i use a selection change event then every time i use an element a new content appear

Comment: how to make like these controller if i add a containers and then hide them the design became more difficult